# Разделить слово на 2 байта

Tags: c#

Привет, есть код, разделяющий беззнаковое слово на 2 беззнаковых байта:

```
        ushort CRC16 = GetCRC16(OutPacket, 2, 0, 0x1021);
        LabelDebug.Text = CRC16.ToString();

        byte CRC16High = (byte)((CRC16 >> 8) & 0xFF);
        LabelDebug2.Text = CRC16High.ToString();

        byte CRC16Low = (byte)(CRC16 & 0xFF);
        LabelDebug3.Text = CRC16Low.ToString();
```

Значение 1-го лэйбла: 1114

Значение 2-го лэйбла: 4 (ожидаю 11)

Значение 3-го лэйбла: 90 (ожидаю 14)

Все числа в Hex. Где ошибка?

Comment: не по сабжу: используйте System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine() для вывода отладочной информации

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка в фразе

> Все числа в Hex.

функция `CRC16.ToString()` возвращает значение в десятичном формате.
Что бы получить значения в Hex нужно использовать `CRC16.ToString("X")` либо `CRC16.ToString("x")`. Подробности смотрим [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2788d0xf.aspx).

Таким образом сделав так:

```
ushort CRC16 = 1114;
Console.WriteLine(CRC16.ToString("X"));

byte CRC16High = (byte)((CRC16 >> 8) & 0xFF);
Console.WriteLine(CRC16High.ToString("X"));

byte CRC16Low = (byte)(CRC16 & 0xFF);
Console.WriteLine(CRC16Low.ToString("X"));
```

получаем на выходе:

```
45A
4
5A
```

Comment: Большой спасибо!